# Hyphenation, long words, linebreaks and extdash

Tags: xetex, hyphenation

Currently I am using LaTeX to write a document in German (= containing many long words).

Sometimes, I wish to place a hyphen at the end of the word. For example:

```
Averylongword-, Anotherverylongword- and Yetanotherverylongword
```

This causes LaTeX to avoid hyphenation inside the first two words resulting in words exceeding the page border. To fix this, I loaded the extdash package which provides the shortcut `\-/` allowing "hyphenation of compound words":

```
Averylongword\-/, Anotherverylongword\-/ and Yetanotherverylongword
```

Now, the words are hyphenated correctly.

However, the usage of `\-/` introduces another issue: Sometimes, a word ending on `\-/,` is placed as the last word of a page but the comma transfers to the following page resulting in:

```
Averyongword-

[pagebreak]

, Anotherverylongword- and Yetanotherverylongword
```

How can I solve this issue and make the comma "stick" to the end of the word?

Comment: Could you pleasee add a minimum (working) example to your post? It would help solvers a lot to start working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}

\begin{document}
\hsize 4cm

We have ababababababa\-/, edededededed\-/~and ififififi\-/methods.
\end{document}
```

yielding

[image]

The solution is in the documentation for `extdash` which says that sometimes a linebreak immediately after the dash is inadmissable, and to use `\=/` instead then.

With `\=/` instead it yields the better

[image]